# Understanding bitwise NOT in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I was trying to understand bitwise NOT in python.

I tried following:

```
print('{:b}'.format(~ 0b0101)) 
print(~ 0b0101)
```

The output is

```
-110
-6
```

I tried to understand the output as follows:

Bitwise negating `0101` gives `1010`. With `1` in most significant bit, python interprets it as a negative number in 2's complement form and to get back corresponding decimal it further takes 2's complement of `1010` as follows:

```
 1010
 0101  (negating)
 0110  (adding 1 to get final value)
```

So it prints it as `-110` which is equivalent to `-6`.

Am I right with this interpretation?

Comment: yes, more or less... A comment in the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c#L4616-L4629) indicates the logical output is `~x as -(x+1)`

Comment: @Aaron code link is not working please update and give it .. waiting .

Comment: @Aaron please explain the link part not able to see it clearly

Comment: @shantanupathak I should have linked a specific version as the line numbers have changed since then. the relevant function is `long_invert` in "cpython/Objects/longobject.c"

Comment: @Aaron Thanks .. now i can see that ~x is implemented as -(x+1)

Answer (score 3):

You're half right..

The value is indeed represented by `~x == -(x+1)` (add one and invert), but the explanation of why is a little misleading.

[Two's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#) numbers require setting the MSB of the integer, which is a little difficult if the number can be an arbitrary number of bits long (as is the case with python). Internally python keeps a separate number (there are optimizations for short numbers however) that tracks how long the digit is. When you `print` a negative int using the binary format: `f'{-6:b}`, it just slaps a negative sign in front of the binary representation of the positive value (one's compliment). Otherwise, how would python determine how many leading one's there should be? Should positive values *always* have leading zeros to indicate they're positive? Internally it does indeed use two's compliment for the math though.

If we consider signed 8 bit numbers (and display all the digits) in 2's compliment your example becomes:

```
~ 0000 0101:  5
= 1111 1010: -6
```

So in short, python is performing correct bitwise negation, however the display of negative binary formatted numbers is misleading.

Comment: NOT Able to interpret following with your logic ???

>>> bin(-27)



'-0b11011'

>>> ~(-27)

26

Answer (score 2):

Python integers are arbitrarily long, so if you invert 0b0101, it would be 1111...11111010.  How many ones do you write?  Well, a 4-bit twos complement -6 is 1010, and a 32-bit twos complement -6 is 11111111111111111111111111111010.  So an arbitrarily long -6 could ideally just be written as -6.

Check what happens when ~5 is masked to look at the bits it represents:

```py
>>> ~5
-6
>>> format(~5 & 0xF,'b')
'1010'
>>> format(~5 & 0xFFFF,'b')
'1111111111111010'
>>> format(~5 & 0xFFFFFFFF,'b')
'11111111111111111111111111111010'
>>> format(~5 & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,'b')
'11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111010'
```

A negative decimal representation makes sense and you must mask to limit a representation to a specific number of bits.