# Understanding Python's bitwise NOT

Tags: python

I was trying to understand bitwise NOT in python.
I tried following:

```
>>> ~0b0
-1

>>> 0b1
1
```

Why is this the case? As per my understanding, `~0b0` is `0b1`. But seems that python interprets it `-1` in 2's complement, but `0b1` is getting interpreted as `1`.

Why is this so?
More importantly, how and why does python determines when to interpret number or MSB of binary string  negative?

Comment: ~ is bitwise flip. You flip ALL the bits. so for 8 bits `00000000` becomes `11111111` which is -1. In your example you don't see the trailing zero bits and the sign bit. `~a` and `-a` are not the same.

Comment: so with `~0b0` it is doing 8 bit calculation to have `11111111`?

Comment: 8 bit is just an example to see what is happening there. I don'T know how much bit is used there. But this happens for 8, 16, 32, 64, etc bits too... You just don't see the leading 0 bits

Comment: Python ints don't have a max value so the discussion about the number of bits is to just simplify things. You can find the source code for the bitwise NOT [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/longobject.c#L4616=)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding bitwise NOT in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72241864/understanding-bitwise-not-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Python interprets a word of binary bits as a negative number when

a) the sign bit is set (the most significant bit of a word)

and

b) the str or repr method is called (to get the string representation or value representation of a word).

or, implicitly, any time you treat the word as a number.

Comment: I can't find the val method. Do you mean the `repr` built-in? I believe that's the one called in the REPL

Comment: @EDG956 Thank you. I just filled in a generic answer because one still hadn't been added -- I don't use python much anymore

Answer (score 0):

Per-spec:

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its integer argument. The bitwise inversion of `x` is defined as `-(x+1)`.

because semantically Python's integers are always signed and manipulated as two's complement.